# R - Como generalizar uma função caso falte informação no data.frame

Tags: r, funções, if, rmarkdown

Criei a função abaixo para calcular a estatística descritiva de certas empresas separadas entre as 5 regiões do Brasil e pelo total e apresentar em uma tabela.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

teste_medias_regiao <- function(base,var_conta,var_regiao){

  var_conta <- enquo(var_conta)
  var_regiao <- enquo(var_regiao)
  base <- base

  resultado_reg <- base %>% group_by(!!var_regiao) %>% summarise(Minímo = min(!!var_conta),
                                                                 Média = mean(!!var_conta),
                                                                 Mediana = median(!!var_conta),
                                                                 Máximo = max(!!var_conta),
                                                                 Variância =  var(!!var_conta),
                                                                 Desv.Pad. =  sd(!!var_conta)
                                                                 ) 

  resultado_br <- base %>% summarise(regiao = "Brasil", 
                                     Minímo = min(!!var_conta),
                                     Média = mean(!!var_conta),
                                     Mediana = median(!!var_conta),
                                     Máximo = max(!!var_conta),
                                     Variância =  var(!!var_conta),
                                     Desv.Pad. =  sd(!!var_conta)
                                     )

  resultado <- merge(resultado_br,resultado_reg, all=TRUE); remove(resultado_reg,resultado_br)

  resultado <- as.data.frame(t(resultado))
  resultado <- resultado %>% mutate(`Teste/Região`=row.names(.)) %>% select(`Teste/Região`,everything())

  names(resultado)[2:7] <- c("Brasil","C-Oeste","Nordeste", "Norte", "Sudeste","Sul")  
  resultado <- resultado[-1,]

  rownames(resultado) <- NULL

  resultado %>%  kable("markdown", escape = F) %>%
                 kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)

}



teste_medias_regiao(empresa_pl, CircRLP,regiao)
```

**Problema:** Quando o data.frame não possui empresa em uma das 5 regiões, a função quebra em `names(resultado)[2:7]`.

Alguma sugestão de como resolver isso? E preencher a coluna Regiao com N/A ou 0?

Exemplo de base com todas as regiões:

> structure(list(CircRLP = c(26240195.62, 136394073.76, 520685437.41, 
>   141563722.92, 1116797.53, 6944476.06, 826787775.92, 61622254.35, 
>   418733960.49, 3830627358.88), regiao = c("Nordeste", "Sudeste",  "Sul", "Centro-Oeste", "Sudeste", "Sudeste", "Sudeste", "Norte", 
>   "Sudeste", "Sudeste")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Exemplo de base faltando um região:

> structure(list(CircRLP = c(26240195.62, 136394073.76, 520685437.41, 
>   141563722.92, 1116797.53, 6944476.06, 826787775.92, 61622254.35, 
>   418733960.49, 3830627358.88), regiao = c("Nordeste", "Sudeste",  "Nordeste", "Centro-Oeste", "Sudeste", "Sudeste", "Sudeste",
>   "Nordeste",  "Sudeste", "Sudeste")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class =
>   "data.frame")

Comment: Tente utilizar o argumento ```na.rm = TRUE```, ele fará com que a função ignore valores faltantes.

Comment: Bom dia, não sei se você já resolveu, escrevo ainda assim. O erro provavelmente deve ser pela diferença no número de colunas entre o vetor de títulos e resultados. Seria bom ver a mensagem de erro. Se eu entendi bem a situação você poderia já atribuir o título no summarise de acordo, porque aí já seriam de acordo com os dados existentes, eliminando a necessidade daquela linha onde ocorre o erro.

Comment: Ola @YvesCavalcanti, obrigado por comentar!  Onde estava aparecendo o erro, resolvi da seguinte forma: `names(resultado)[2:ncol(resultado)] <- resultado[1,2:ncol(resultado)]`, então criei uma tabela vazia com todas as regiões e nome das linhas. Depois atribui os valores da tabela calculada (resultado) para ela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onde estava aparecendo o erro, resolvi da seguinte forma: `names(resultado)[2:ncol(resultado)] <- resultado[1,2:ncol(resultado)]`, então criei uma tabela vazia com todas as regiões e nome das linhas. Depois atribui os valores da tabela calculada (resultado) para ela

Ficou algo do tipo:

```r
names(resultado)[2:ncol(resultado)] <- resultado[1,2:ncol(resultado)]
  resultado <- resultado[-1,]
  
  tabela_completa <- data.frame(Teste=character(),
                           Brasil=character(),
                           `Centro-Oeste`=character(),
                           Nordeste=character(), 
                           Norte=character(), 
                           Sudeste=character(),
                           Sul=character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 
 
 tabela_completa <- merge(tabela_completa,resultado,all=TRUE)
 remove(resultado_reg,resultado_br,resultado)
```